# Кастомизация QMessageBox C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Ранее я задавал вопрос:

Возможно ли в стандартном QMessageBox (чтобы свой диалог не писать), кнопки сделать по центру?

Я пробовал делать QHBoxLayout размещать в него 2 кнопки, а потом это лейаут добалять в QMessageBox. Не получилось.

Потом делал так:

```
QPushButton * abort = question.addButton("Abort", QMessageBox::NoRole);
```

И в стилях пытался марджинами поправить. Кнопка сдивнулась. Но проблема была в том, что марджин увеличивает размер виджета, и кнопка как бы больше становится, т.е. при клике правее кнопки она нажимается.

Я смог это реализовать так:

Распечатал все виджеты и их свойства у QMessageBox:

```
const auto widgets = msgbox->findChildren<QWidget*>();
for (const auto widget : widgets)
{
const QMetaObject * metaobject = widget->metaObject();
 int count = metaobject->propertyCount();
 for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
 {
     QMetaProperty metaproperty = metaobject->property(i);
     const char * name = metaproperty.name();
     QVariant value = widget->property(name);
     qDebug() << "NAME : " << name << ", VALUE : " << value;
 }
}
```

У QMessageBox есть виджет qt_msgbox_buttonbox, к которому если обращаться по имени в файле .qss через #qt_msgbox_buttonbox и установив ему свойство qproperty-centerButtons: true. То кнопки выровняются по центру.

Теперь мне нужно сдвинуть картинку у QMessageBox. И здесь снова я встал в тупик.

В стилях я пробовал установить виджету qt_msgboxex_icon_label margin обращаясь к нему по имени #qt_msgboxex_icon_label в файле .qss. И вот в чем загвоздка. В Linux такой код работает, и картинка спокойно позиционируется, а вот в Windows нет.

Пробовал такой вот код использовать:

```
QGridLayout * grid = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(msgbox->layout());
    if (grid)
    {
        QLabel * label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>((grid->itemAtPosition(0, 0))->widget());
        if (label)
        {
            label->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Но такой код двигает картинку, но не ее Label. Не могу в общем спозиционировать в нужное место картинку в QMessageBox

Comment: как вариант, можете написать свой виджет, например QMyMessageBox и использовать его в дальнейшем.

Comment: QMessageBox наследован от QDialog, т.е. его отличие в том что были добавлены: иконка, текст и кнопки. Так что, вам просто нужно будет повторить.

Comment: Вопрос в том и был. Чтобы сделать кнопки по центру в стандартном 
 QMessageBox и не писать свой

Comment: Посмотрите на функционал QDialogButtonBox http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#details

Answer (score 1):

Не забывайте, что Qt - продукт с открытым исходным кодом, и всегда можно покапаться внутри исходников. Так, использую метаобъектную систему Qt, можно легко установить [кнопки в диалоге](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/dialogs/qmessagebox.cpp#L280-L282) по центру

```
QMessageBox *dlg = ...;
if(QDialogButtonBox * box = dlg->findChild<QDialogButtonBox*>(QString("qt_msgbox_buttonbox")))
  box->setCenterButtons(true);
```

А если еще немного [извернуться](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/dialogs/qmessagebox.cpp#L306-L308), то и иконку можно подвинуть

```
QMessageBox *dlg = ...;
if(QLabel * lbl = dlg->findChild<QLabel*>("qt_msgboxex_icon_label")) {
  if(QGridLayout * lay = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(dlg->layout()) ) {
    // Перый элемент - иконка
    delete lay->takeAt(0);
    lay->addWidget(lbl, 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt::AlignCenter);
  }
}
```

Но использовать такое решение можно только на свой страх и риск: нет гарантий, что разработчики не поменяют что-то в будущих релизах.